# How to check for UIButton object when removing all CALayers from a view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, calayer

I have a reinit method that removes all existing CALayer objects from a UIScrollView. This works fine on all of my CALayer and CATextLayer objects, but I have a UIButton object in this view that I wish to leave alone. It appears that my code is affecting the layer of the UIButton object, leaving it in an unintended state (no longer visible). Is there a way I can I check whether a layer is the layer property of my UIButton object, so that I can bypass removal? Thanks.

```
- (void) reinit {
    for (CALayer *layer in [myScrollView.layer.sublayers copy]){
        [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by assigning a name to the button's layer before adding it to the view, and later checking for that name:

```
[myButton.layer setName: @"ButtonLayer"];

- (void)reinit {

    for (CALayer *layer in [myScrollView.layer.sublayers copy]){
       if ([[layer name] isEqualToString:@"ButtonLayer"]) {
           NSLog(@"Button layer found.");
       else {
          [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
      } 
    }
}
```